# k-means clustering issue voice data

Tags: clustering, python, k-means, speech-recognition

I'm getting an issue in my k-means I don't know if it my data-set or what anything else. 
Why i got thia flowing point in the right side of the image?

```
# Fitting K-Means to the dataset
# Fitting the input data
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=best_clusters, init = 'k-means++', random_state = 14, max_iter=300, n_init=20)  
kmeans.fit(X_Train_Scaled_neutre)
y_kmeans = kmeans.fit_predict(X_Train_Scaled_neutre) 



# Getting de cluster labels
labels_kmeans = kmeans.labels_
# Centroid values
centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_


plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
plt.scatter(X_Train_Scaled_neutre[:, 0], X_Train_Scaled_neutre[:, 1], c=y_kmeans, s=50, cmap='viridis')
plt.scatter(centers[:, 0], centers[:, 1], c='black', s=200, alpha=0.5);
```

[image]

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause you have a ton of points the far right that are over lapping and not visible in graph. Count the points greater than x= 0.5. To solve the problem delete duplicate entries in the dataset

Comment: Thanks, supplicate lines you want to say? I've normalized the data before doing the k-means. Pleas explain me what do you mean by duplicated entries.

Comment: When I check duplicated rows, it was just two. I've dropped them but this does not fix the issue.

Comment: Okay. Are you sure you not clipping your dataset? Why are there so many points at x=1? The problem is that when the points are initilized, the ones on the right stay on the right because of the large gap in between. Count the number of points above and below 0.5. Your data need more features for k-means to distinguish better

Comment: Besides what do you think is unnatural here? If you set k=3 you will get the middle two and the right most part as categories which is what a human would guess as well. Your model is fine, its your input data.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look carefully my data.